# HitTest is not returning proper value

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

we recently migrated code base from old visual studio(6.0) to 2019. we started seeing the Issue with mcHitTest values. The exact code is working fine in the old system. I would like to understand what's wrong with this function and has anything been changed in MCHITTESTINFO. the requirement is to remove holiday If it on the same day or we should pop up dialog box saying **ADD HOLIDAY** If it is not a holiday. The problem hear is, it is not even entering into the block where we have all this code. Please help me out.

```
MCHITTESTINFO mcHitTest;    
SYSTEMTIME nSelectedDate;
INT_PTR nRet = -1;

mcHitTest.cbSize = sizeof(MCHITTESTINFO);
mcHitTest.pt = point;

DWORD dw = HitTest(&mcHitTest);

if(dw == MCHT_TITLEYEAR || dw == MCHT_TITLEMONTH || dw == MCHT_CALENDARDATENEXT || dw == MCHT_CALENDARDATEPREV)
{
    DBUG_VOID_RETURN;
}   
else if (dw == MCHT_CALENDARDATE && IsDoubleClick())
{   
    char altmsg[1000]= "";
    errReport(SEVERITY_INFO, CMOI_INFO, "krishna inside else if");
    nSelectedDate = mcHitTest.st;
    
    
    pszCalCode = ((CCalendarDlg*)m_pParent)->GetSelCalendarCode();      
    
    if(!IsHoliday(nSelectedDate))
    {   
        errReport(SEVERITY_INFO, CMOI_INFO, "krishna inside isnot a holiday");
        CAddHolNameDlg dlgAddHol(&nSelectedDate, pszCalCode, this);
        nRet = dlgAddHol.DoModal();
            
        switch(nRet)
        {
    
        case IDOK:      
            LoadAndRefreshHolidayList(&m_pHolidayList, &m_nHolidayCount, pszCalCode);
            DisplayHoliday();
            DBUG_VOID_RETURN;           
            
        case IDCANCEL:
            DBUG_VOID_RETURN;           
            
        default:
            DBUG_VOID_RETURN;           
        };      
    }
    else
    {       
        errReport(SEVERITY_INFO, CMOI_INFO, "krishna inside else");
        pszDate.Format("%d/%d/%d", nSelectedDate.wMonth, nSelectedDate.wDay, nSelectedDate.wYear);
        LOADSTRINGRESOURCE(m_pszErrorCaption, IDS_DLG_HC_DELETEHOL, IDS_DLG_HC_DELETEHOL);
        pszRemoveHoliday.Format(IDS_MB_HC_DELETEHOL, (LPCSTR)GetHolidayName(nSelectedDate));
        nRet = MessageBox(pszRemoveHoliday, m_pszErrorCaption, MB_YESNO|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        switch(nRet)
        {   
        case IDYES:
            nStatus =   DeleteHoliday((LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)pszCalCode, (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)pszDate);
            LoadAndRefreshHolidayList(&m_pHolidayList, &m_nHolidayCount, pszCalCode);
            DisplayHoliday();
            DBUG_VOID_RETURN;       
        
        case IDNO:
                DBUG_VOID_RETURN;
            
        default:
            DBUG_VOID_RETURN;
        };
    }    
}

errReport(SEVERITY_INFO, CMOI_INFO, "krishna going to call  OnLButtonDown before exit from onbuttondown");
CMonthCalCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point) ;
errReport(SEVERITY_INFO, CMOI_INFO, "krishna going to return");
DBUG_VOID_RETURN;

}
```

Comment: The code you've posted seems truncated. Please post a comprehensible version of the code. Is it a function? Where is the signature? Is it a class or method?

Comment: void CCustomMonthCalCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
 DBUG_ENTER("CCustomMonthCalCtrl::OnLButtonDown");
 errReport(SEVERITY_INFO, CMOI_INFO, "krishna inside OnLButtonDown");
 SINT4 nStatus;
 CString m_pszErrorCaption;
 CString pszRemoveHoliday;
 CString pszCalCode,pszDate;
 MCHITTESTINFO mcHitTest; 
 SYSTEMTIME nSelectedDate;

Comment: Yes it is, void CCustomMonthCalCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)

Comment: @user3291891 Is `MCHITTESTINFO` one of those structures that need to be zeroed out before you use it?  If so, I don't see it being done in the code you're showing, and you were lucky the code worked with such an old compiler.  A simple way to zero out the structure is to do this: `MCHITTESTINFO mcHitTest = {};`.  You could not do that with the old compiler, but now with modern C++, this is the way to zero initialize the struct.

Comment: Have you determined what specific value it does return, and are you sure that the problem isn't `IsDoubleClick`?

Comment: IsDoubleClick is working absolutely fine. Because  I removed dw == MCHT_CALENDARDATE && and kept only IsDoubleClick()) then contril is coming into this function. Moreover I tried to get the return value from DWORD dw = HitTest(&mcHitTest); hitTest funtion. It is not entering into any f the expected values. I suspect hitTest is not being filled properly.  DWORD dw = HitTest(&mcHitTest);

Comment: I initialized as mentioned MCHITTESTINFO mcHitTest = {}; But didn't work

Comment: Zero-initialization isn't enough. You also need to set its `cbSize` and `pt` fields appropriately (as spelled out in [MonthCal_HitTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-monthcal_hittest)). Though it's not clear from the question, where the code fails, or how. Does `HitTest` get executed? If so, does it return the expected results?

Comment: @user3291891 What is the unexpected value that it returns?

Comment: HitTest did not return the expected values. I printed POINT object coordinates. Where ever I click on holiday it is returning the same x and y values.  I did print smcHitTest.st.wYear, mcHitTest.st.wMonth, mcHitTest.st.wMonth but all of them are zeros.

Comment: x and y co-ordinates are fine but mcHitTest.st values are coming as zeros

Comment: To repeat the question again: what value *did* it return? It’s not one that you expect, but what value was it?

Comment: I got all zeros nSelectedDate = mcHitTest.st;
  //this->ScreenToClient()
  str1.Format("select date is: %04d/%02d/%02d", nSelectedDate.wYear, nSelectedDate.wMonth, nSelectedDate.wMonth);
  AfxMessageBox(str1);

Comment: Are you feeding the correct `point` into the structure? We cannot see where it came from. It needs to be relative to the Month Calendar control's window rectangle.

Comment: It is coming from calendarctrl when I single or double clicked on a date then it is entering into below function void CCustomMonthCalCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point).But how to know whether point values are correct or not?

Comment: By observing their values. If they are in the range 0..width and 0..height of the control, they are presumably correct. Although you seem to have implemented your custom `CMonthCalCtrl`-derived control. That's an opportunity to get things wrong. We cannot help you with that, since we cannot see that implementation. Please provide a [mcve]. Make sure that it's **minimal**.

Comment: I would try first with a properly zeroed MCHITTEST structure.  Try this when declaring: `MCHITTESTINFO mcHitTest = {};`.